Can a tiled shower curb be rebuilt without redoing the entire shower?
We had a tub removed and a new tiled shower built. The contractor built the curb crooked to the wall, and it wasn’t caught until after it was tiled. He has committed to correcting it, but is proposing to only demo the curb, a row of floor tile and one of the 16x48 wall tiles on each side.
Question- is this a valid repair plan, or does the entire shower need to be rebuilt because of potential damage to the waterproofing when the curb is demoed?
For context, the same GC told us he couldn’t simply replace the tile floor in another shower with demoing part of the walls and redoing the pan/waterproofing. Googling did not turn up any clear answers for me. 

Yes , what the contractor proposes can be done.  I have done repairs this myself with much success.   I would get an addendum to the contract that outlines the warranty on the work.

I'd guess that for the other shower where he didn't want to only replace the floor tile is that in that case he feared being held responsible for future leaks in parts of the shower he hadn't touched, and the way he felt comfortable mitigating that risk was to do part of the walls too. In this new shower he's already responsible for the whole thing, so there's no additional risk to him by only doing what he considers necessary to fix the error.

Regarding the shower floor tile replacement,  The tile removal will cause distress to the underlying drypack cement base and possibly the PVC barrier.  The PVC barrier goes vertically up the wall behind the tile and whatever backerboard is used . So the GC wants to be able to be sure he can get new ;iner where it should be.  This sounds like a conscientious GC. I would trust him.   However an option may be to tile over the existing tile.  In my location it is done fairly often and the tile stores carry a thin set specially modified to be used when tillng over tile.

How crooked is crooked? Maybe this is something that you take a discount for and move on.
